# How extend task provided by plugin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-js

I have `kotlin2js` plugin with task `compileKotlin2Js`. I configure it like this:

```
val compileKotlin2Js: Kotlin2JsCompile by tasks
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
    main = "call"
    outputFile = "${projectDir}/build/app.js"
}
```

Now I want to create similar task, but with other `kotlinOptions`. For example:

```
.kotlinOptions {
    main = "noCall"
    outputFile = "${projectDir}/build/lib.js"
}
```

How to do it?

UPDATE: I also tried to do some thing like this:

```
tasks.register<Kotlin2JsCompile>("myCompile2Js") {
    kotlinOptions {
        main = "noCall"
        outputFile = "${projectDir}/build/lib.js"
    }
}
```

But it produce error:

```
Execution failed for task ':myCompile2Js'.
> lateinit property destinationDirProvider has not been initialized
```

I also tried to specify `destinationDir`. Error disappear, but such task does not produce any build.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I believe something like the following should do the trick:

```
tasks.register<Kotlin2JsCompile>("myCompile2Js") {
    kotlinOptions {
        main = "noCall"
        outputFile = "${projectDir}/build/lib.js"
    }
}
```

Or if you need a reference to the task later on:

```
val myCompile2Js by tasks.creating(Kotlin2JsCompile::class)
myCompile2Js.kotlinOptions {
    main = "noCall"
    outputFile = "${projectDir}/build/lib.js"
}
```

Comment: I tried it too. But it don' work. Produce error `Execution failed for task ':myCompile2Js'.
> lateinit property destinationDirProvider has not been initialized`. And I also tried to specify `destinationDir`. It avoid error, but task do nothing.

Comment: @leaf I see then. Maybe you can take a look at how they create the task in the plugin, maybe there is more initialization required when creating a custom one. I don't the details of the kotlin JS plugin myself unfortunately.